# jquery ajax contact form redirects to contact.php instead of catching php echo and executing sucess function

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, contacts

I have a contact form php+jquery+HTML.the form div is hidden in index.HTML,until contact button is presses.Jquery works,Ajax call posts needed data to php,which echoes a response.The problem is when php echoes,instead of remaining on same page without refreshing,browser redirects to contact.php,where the echo is showed correctly.I think the Ajax part won't catch the response from server,although syntax is the same in all tutorials.please assist.
html part:

**HTML**

```
<div id = 'contact_form'>
    <div id = 'result'></div>
        <form id="contactform" action="js/contact.php" method="POST"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="row">
                <input id="name" class="input" name="name" type="text" required = 'true' value="" size="30" placeholder='Nome'/>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <input id="email" class="input" name="email" type="text" required = 'true' value="" size="30" placeholder = 'Email'/>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <textarea id="message" class="input" name="message" rows="7" cols="50" required = 'true' placeholder = 'Messagio'></textarea>
            </div>

            <input id="submit_button" class = 'myButton' type="submit" value="Manda messagio" />
        </form>
    </div>                      
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('#submit_btn').click(function(){
    var user_name = $("input#name").val();

    if (user_name == "") {
        $("input#name").focus().addClass('active');
        return false;
     }

    var user_email = $("input#email").val();

    if (!$("input#email").val().match(/^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/)) {
            $("input#email").focus().addClass('active');
            return false;
     }

     var msg = $("textarea#message").val();

    if (message == "") {
        $("textarea#message").focus().addClass('active');
        return false;
     }

     var dataString = 'name='+ user_name + '&email=' + user_email +'message = ' + msg;
    //alert (dataString);return false;


    // Send the request
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "contact.php",
        data: dataString,
        success: function(d) {
            console.log(d);
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
    $toEmail = "x@gmail.com";
    $subject = "dal tuo sito ";
    $mailHeaders = "From: " . $_POST["name"] . "<". $_POST["email"] .">\r\n";

    if(mail($toEmail,$subject,$_POST["message"], $mailHeaders)) {
        echo "Mail Sent";
    } else {
        echo "Problem in Sending Mail";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Use `multipart/form-data` when your form includes any `<input type="file">` elements.

Comment: are you sure that js/contact.php is correct? The "js/..." seems to be wrong. Anyways remove the 'action="js/contact.php" method="POST"' part, then either change the type "submit" to "button" or put e.preventDefault and return 0 into the submit handler as suggested in the answers below.

Answer (score 0):

Because you used a submit type input, I recommend you change the submit input for a link like button. And also remove the `action` attr from the form:

**HTML**

```
<a href="javascript:;" id="btn">Send</a>
```

**JS**

```
<script>
    $('#btn').on("click", function(){
        //Your ajax here
        //var dataString = 'name='+ user_name + '&email=' + user_email +'message = ' + msg;
       //alert (dataString);return false;
       // Send the request
       $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "contact.php",
          data: {name: user_name, email: user_email, message: msg}
       }).done(function(response){
          console.log(response);
       });   
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks,did that,now chrome console throws a 'same origin javascript error' thus preventing js from catching php's echo and execute further.Mail is not being sent also.I'm a bit confused at the moment.Seems like if there is no action on the form,the php never gets invoked.

Comment: Yep,after extensive testing done today,there is no avail to execute the ajax call on my host.tryed setting headers in php->nothing(allow-origin-accept*) or something similar,nothing.tryed the javascript on the same page,thus avoiding same origin policy,no avail.I don't know what to do further. tryed a php redirect via header('location ..//index.html')after mail succeded,but that does not work either.I am lost at this point.all tutorials have similar code,and it seems to work

Comment: Resolved now.seems like my free hosting injects some stuff in my code so when it has to change folders error 404 is thrown,js gets same origin error and so on.threw all my files in one folder,working now.thank you very much for the help

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the same button you can change your js.

```js
$('#submit_btn').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
//YOUR CODE HERE  
}
```